# An error, when importing an image in React Js app

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error: **InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/showcaseimage.c2c0ae9f.jpg') is not a valid name.**
Why do I get it on an image import ? (I'll include my file tree. but i think the issue is not with that). The name of the image inside of the image folder is showcaseimage.jpg

[my file tree and how i imported an image inside of my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym4Uq.jpg)

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

Imported images are **not** components, they are URLs (or they will be by the time a bundler has worked its magic).

You need an img element or other thing that accepts a URL to use it.

```
import myImage from '../images/foo.jpeg';

const MyComponent = () => {
    return <img src={myImage} alt="Alternative text goes here as usual" />;
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. Totally forgot about it ! You saved me)))